# Download PDF from redirected URL to local storage

Tags: python, pdf, download, python-requests

I'm trying to download PDFs from a list of re-directed URLs. I want to go through a list and download the PDFs into my local drive.

**The code that I have so far:**

```py
for i in announcement_url: 
  local_filename = r'C:\Users\jorda\Documents\University\DataScience\PDFDataScraper'
  with requests.get(i, stream=True, allow_redirects =True) as r:
      with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
          shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f) 
          print(i)
```

I was under the impression that this would download on to my local drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save the file to a given path (no copy required):

```
for i, url in enumerate(announcement_url): 
  local_filename = "path_to_local_directory"
  local_filename = local_filename+ f"pdffilename_{i}.pdf"
  with requests.get(url, allow_redirects =True) as r: #get the url
        print(url)
        open(local_filename, 'wb').write(r.content) #save content with a filename
```